# Excel - Get hourly averages for data spanning 1 year (8760 data points)

Tags: excel

I have an excel document with values for every hour for every day of a year.
In total there are 365*24=8760 values.

I would like to get the average value at every hour, (etc at 00:00, 01:00, 02:00..)
I was thinking maybe to sum every 24th value and then divide it by 365 but I don't know how to sum every 24th value.

Does anyone know how to do that?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: You have 2 columns, right? One for the time sequence and one for the values.     Do you need the average of what? Is it the average per day? It is unclear for me.

Comment: Yes i have 2 columns, one with Date(year-month-day-time)  and one with value(kWh). I would want to get an average for every hour. So basically sum all the values corresponding to 1am, 2am, 3am etc. In the end i would like to make a graph where I can see during what hour i have the highest kWh.

Comment: So I have 365 values for 01:00(corresponding to all the days during the year.). However they are spaced on every 24th row. I would like to add all of those 365 values and then get an average for that the kWh is at 01:00. I would like to do this for every hour so for (00:00, 01:00, 02:00 ... 23:00). Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The clearer way of doing it is using a column to get the hour of each data point and adding a **AVERAGEIF formula** to calculate the average of every hour.

1. I am assuming your date/time is on A2:A8761 and the values on B2:B8761.
2. On C2, add the formula `=HOUR(A2)` and drag it down to find the hour of every data observation (for newer excel versions you can also
   do `=HOUR(A2:A8761)` and the formula will automatically spill down). The results are numbers from 0 to 23.

**Building the summary table:**

3. Add a column listing the numbers 0 to 23 to represent the 24 hours. I did it on column E2:E25. Note that those are numbers, not date/time.
4. On F2, add the formula `=AVERAGEIF($C$2:$C$8761,E2,$B$2:$B$8761)` to calculate the average of the hours listed on column E. Then, drag it down. Finally, you will have the values you need on F2:F25.

Find bellow my result.

[image]

Please let me know if you have any question so I can improve the answer.